# How to add custom font(ttf) to react.js application

Tags: reactjs, custom-font

I want to add SFProText font(ttf) into my react application. I when through this [article](https://www.yudiz.com/adding-new-fonts-in-react-js/). I want to know what is the easiest way to add a font.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

I want to know that is there any easy way like adding google font (above code line) ?

I checked this [article](https://www.yudiz.com/adding-new-fonts-in-react-js/) also. But I feel that there should be a easy way than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the font inline using

```
<style>
    @import url({`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${family.replace(/ /g, '+')}`});
</style>
```

and then do inline fontFamily maybe

```
 style={{ fontFamily: `${family},${category}` }}
```